# codeIgniter print result failed on view

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get and send data from MySQL to views in my CodeIgniter.

This is my function in my Model :

```
public function getProduct()
{
   // EDIT : remove ; from ->from('table') and add ' ' to select ->select('*');
   $a = $this->db->select('*')
             -from('table')
             ->get();
   return $a->result();
}
```

This is my Function in controller :

```
public function sendView()
{ 
    $d['product'] = $this->model->getProduct();
    $this->load->view('product', $d);
}
```

This is my views :

```
<a href="#"><?php echo $product; ?></a>
```

It's not getting all product data from MySQL.

Comment: in your view try using print_r rather than echo

Comment: You will get array when using `result();` so `echo $product;` won't work, try `var_dump()` r `print_r()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You was return the data using result. But, check your model `->from('table');` dont use `;` in the end of that row. So, just `->from('table')`

So what you need to do in you view is

```
<?php foreach($product as $pr)
      { ?>
         <a href="#"><?php echo $pr->example_product_name; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

You can try it, change `example_product_name` into your `column_name` you wanted to call it.

Comment: yeah, its works now after using foreach. But, can I use `for` loop than `foreach` ?

Comment: Nope, just keep using `foreach`. Because in `for` you need to set the interger data for maximum looping example `for ($i=1; $i<X; $i++)`. So, you need to set that `X` for maximum data shown. If you're using foreach, you will get all data that returned from your query.